# How to access google map's container element

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I get the HTML element in which was supplied to the google map object?

For example if I have `<div id='mymap'></div>`  and then supply `#mymap` to `var map;` how can I access `#mymap` from the `map` object?

Jquery can be involved, but I'd bet there is a google map function that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation of the Google Maps Javascript API v3 `google.maps.Map` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) it is:

> **getDiv()**
>
> Return Value:  Node

(it would be nice if it specified that it returns the `<div>` used to render the `google.maps.Map`)

Answer (score 0):

After some tricky googling I found the answer to be `map.getDiv()`